# Increase resolution with enlarging rendered area / or snap rendered area to the edges of geometry

Tags: camera, resolution

Let's say I have 3 cubes attached and I need 2 renders from above.
[image]

The first render should be square and aligned exactly to the size of a middle cube. There is no problem with it. I set the resolution to 1080x1080 and zoom in.
[image]

But the second render I want to have Y resolution the same with X resolution bigger to contain all 3 cubes. It's logical that I should just increase X resolution. But when I do so it makes the rendered area SMALLER not bigger!
[image]

What I need to do now is to move camera up by Z axis and have a painful guessing game trying to catch the same number of pixels for my geometry on both renders.

I added the red rectangle in the middle to make it more visual. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the same number of pixels for this red rectangle on both renders. It's important for me as I plan to use PNG images with transparency as layers in another software so the scale should be perfectly matched.

[image]

The way I fix it right now (make render, send it to Photoshop, see if I need to zoom in or out to match the scale and make it again) is very annoying and time consuming...

So I'll be very grateful for any help or advise!

Comment: Hello :). I think [@Duarte](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) will know how to do this using orthographic camera. You can hit him up in the chat ;)

Comment: @Jachym Michal thanks! not sure I have a chat option though..

Comment: Hey :). Simply join our main Renderfarm chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

Comment: @JachymMichal thanks I did! by the way I can't understand why my mention of a @ name doesn't work...

Comment: I think you can only mention people in chat who were participating in that chat room before. Anyway see if https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64914/setting-camera-to-position-where-it-can-render-a-seamless-repetable-orthographic/64920#64920 helps with camera scale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default sensor fit is *"Auto"* - modifying output resolution only affects the smaller sides:

[image]

You can go to your camera settings to change the sensor fit to *"Vertical"*: [image]

[image]

Related: [How to set specific sample spacing (meters in between each pixel) for a Blender Cycles Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/213980/60486)

And a great thorough explanation by Gordon Brinkmann here: [Why does reducing Resolution X increase my camera's FOV and increasing it reduce FOV?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/220034/60486)

Comment: wow it's great! thank you very much! can you please also clarify what width and height under Sensor Fit represent?

Comment: @LiliaLilia both a human eye and a camera sensor are not points - they have area. In case of a camera, the sensor is typically rectangular (I don't know of a circular sensor but I imagine some could be created for some scientific purposes). Since Blender already deals with quite a few effects simulating taking a picture (like depth of field), it makes sense to allow to specify camera sensor dimensions.